# ASP.NET disappear message after a while

Tags: asp.net

On a page I display a message against button click.Message is a Label control. My problem is that once button is clicked message appear but it should automatically disappear after 3 seconds of time. I am working on ASP.NET in .NET framework 4.0

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need some client-side scripting, e.g. jQuery / JavaScript. Bind to the onclick event of your button, set a delay once the event is hit, and then hide your message.